# The output order is different if setTimeout is present

Tags: javascript, recursion, settimeout

The code to return the tree structure to console.log with a recursive function as shown below. I added setTimeout because I need some delays during the code processing, but when I add it, the order of processing is output in a completely different format. Also, the delay time does not seem to be constant.

The intended value is

If there is a child in the node after the first category title is searched, the second category title is searched by recursive, and the children value is inquired again, and then the third .. .. If setTimeout is added, The whole will be sown first, then the second whole, then the third whole, and so on.

Why is this happening?

```
            var time = 0;
            function searchTree(v, t){

                $(v).each(function(i,k){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        if (t == 'clone'){
                            console.log(k.sCategoryTitle);
                            if (k.children){
                                searchTree(k.children,'clone');
                            }
                        }
                    }, time = time + 100);
                });
            }
```

sample code : http://jsfiddle.net/uahg5qd9/3/

Comment: better use for loop, and once your match is found then break that loop, and call recursive function.

Comment: `setTimeout` is asynchronous. So `each` will loop through the whole array and set a bunch of timeouts each offset by 100.

Answer (score 0):

you have make your function synchronous.

try below code, if it will help you. here i have removed loop and put another synchronous function to make it synchronous.

```js
var time = 100;
function searchTree(v, t){
    var i=0;
    function loop(){
        if(i<v.length){
            let k = v[i];    
            if (t == 'clone'){
                console.log(k.sCategoryTitle);
                if (k.children){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        time = time + 100;
                        searchTree(k.children,'clone');
                    },time);
                }else{
                    i++;
                    loop();
                }
            }else{
                i++;
                loop();
            }
        }else{
            i++;
            loop();
        }
    }
    loop();
}
```